# GET and table href placement?

Tags: php

I am very new to php.

I have spent a few hours on this. I am just wondering where and how to place my $_GET function, I am wanting to place a $_GET 'somewhere' in index.php below to link from HREF to the table in another .php - this is my GET - ***$_GET['var1']***

```
      ..........

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Production WHERE Production.Title = 'Cats'";
      $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
      $query->execute();
      $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );



      foreach( $results as $row ){ 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Title']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['BasicTicketPrice']. "</td>";
        echo ('<td><a href="perf.php?id=".$row['var1']."">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" 
              class="register" /></a></td>');
        echo "</tr>";

      }
      ?>

        ...............
```

If I have a similar page with the same structure where do I place $rowid = $_GET['rowid']? To get the information. Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

The only GET value you've set in this example is `id`
,
`var1` is fetched from the DB/Table but `?xxx=` dictates the GET array key name...

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an `<input>` inside an `<a>`. Link somewhere **or** submit a form. You can't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what your problem is. But the variable $_GET['var1'] contains only a value on your page index.php when the query string in the href attribute contains index.php?var1=".$row['var1']."
In your example you are using id instead. You would need $_GET['id'] instead.

Comment: So if I use a form with a href, what would I need to add to link the button produced to a table in the next PHP file? Like I said I'm new and been trying all sorts of ways to use a button to link to a table in a specific . PHP file. Cheers.

Comment: if you have the form on page.php with:
<form action="otherpage.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" name="var1" value=".$row['var1'].">

You will be able to access on otherpage.php:
$_GET['var1'] containing the value of $row['var1']